# concate() long siring in mysql store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concatenation, dynamic-queries

i am try to execute dynamic query for that i am using CONCAT() function. but i think my string/query in long so CONCAT() is not working.

```
set @query:=CONCAT(' SELECT (select GROUP_CONCAT(sp.specialization) FROM DSpecialization_Master dsp LEFT JOIN 
Specialization_Master sp on sp.id = dsp.specialization WHERE dsp.profileid in (', @MultiDoctorIds ,') 
) as drspec,pm.id as profileid,dam.city,um.profile_url FROM Profile_Master pm LEFT JOIN DAddress_Master dam on 
dam.profileid = pm.id join Unique_Url_Master um on um.clinicid =dam.id WHERE pm.id in (',@MultiDoctorIds,') 
and dam.id=',@clinicId,'  order by CASE WHEN um.clinic_url=''',@ClinicUrl,''' THEN 1 ELSE 2  end,um.clinic_url   ');

select @query;
```

this is part of store procedure when i execute my SP it show me **@query NULL** but if i shorten my query then i get complete query.

is there another way to concatenate ??

any help appreciated.

Comment: check all the user defined variables. May be one (or more) of them is null.

Comment: by the way, `SELECT CONCAT('asdf',NULL)` results in `null`

Comment: great @ClinicUrl was null it should be ClinicUrl(which is parameter i am passing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `temporary solution` for this is , store your `dynamic query` in `local variable` instead of `sessional variable` with `maximum length` .like below

```
Declare temp_query varchar(4000);

set @query:=CONCAT(' SELECT (select GROUP_CONCAT(sp.specialization) FROM DSpecialization_Master dsp LEFT JOIN 
Specialization_Master sp on sp.id = dsp.specialization WHERE dsp.profileid in (', @MultiDoctorIds ,') 
) as drspec,pm.id as profileid,dam.city,um.profile_url FROM Profile_Master pm LEFT JOIN DAddress_Master dam on 
dam.profileid = pm.id join Unique_Url_Master um on um.clinicid =dam.id WHERE pm.id in (',@MultiDoctorIds,') 
and dam.id=',@clinicId,'  order by CASE WHEN um.clinic_url=''',@ClinicUrl,''' THEN 1 ELSE 2  end,um.clinic_url   ');

select @query into temp_query;
select temp_query;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable like

```
SET @var := hello hello
```

You must quote it

```
MariaDB [(none)]> set @var = hello hello;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'hello' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]> set @var = "hello hello";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> select @var;
+-------------+
| @var        |
+-------------+
| hello hello |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got another one solution:

`GROUP_CONCAT` max length is the limit `(1024 by default)` you should alter the  session-scope length of it like below that will resolve your trouble

```
  SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 25000 ;
```